# powershell classes, gui and events

Tags: powershell, class, user-interface, object, events

I try this code which works correctly :

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize  = '300,150'
$form.Text        = 'Form Test'
$form.TopMost     = $false

$Button1        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text   = "Close"
$Button1.width  = 60
$Button1.height = 30
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Button1.add_Click({[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World." , "My Dialog Box")})

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($Button1))
$form.showDialog()
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work correctly (look at the line Buton1.add_Click). The Dialog Box in Buton1.add_Click() is executed when i launch the program.

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize  = '300,150'
$form.Text        = 'Form Test'
$form.TopMost     = $false

$Button1        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text   = "Close"
$Button1.width  = 60
$Button1.height = 30
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$Button1.add_Click([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World." , "My Dialog Box"))

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($Button1))
$form.showDialog()
```

The objective is to build a class for this form like this :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

Class WindowView : System.Windows.Forms.Form {

    WindowView() {
        $this.ClientSize  = '300,150'
        $this.Text        = 'Test de Form'
        $this.TopMost     = $false

        $Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
        $Button1.text                    = "Close"
        $Button1.width                   = 60
        $Button1.height                  = 30
        $Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        $Button1.add_Click($this.monBoutonFunc_Click())

        $this.Controls.AddRange(@($Button1))
}

    [Void] monBoutonFunc_Click() {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World." , "My Dialog Box")
        $this.monBoutonFunc_Click()
    }
}

$Form1 = [WindowView]::new()
$Form1.Add_Shown({$Form1.Activate()})
$Form1.showDialog()
```

Of course, when the code in Button1.add_Click() is executed at the beginning, the form is closed "before" to be Show.

What is the syntax to register events correctly in powershell object oriented ?

Thank you very much for help and advices

Comment: Look at `Get-Help -Name Register-ObjectEvent`

Comment: Also, your second example doesn't have a scriptblock, so it's erroring out immediately.

Comment: The second example has no error, just the code in the add_range is executed at the launch of the program

Comment: The Register-ObjectEvent seems to be what i'm looking for, i'm trying to use it in the class now

Comment: I got it to accept it with this syntax (I don't think it's pretty): $Button1.add_Click({$this.Parent.monBoutonFunc_Click()})

Comment: Oh, thank you really much Palansen, it is exactly what i looked for :)